# How to make python's coverage library include doctests

Tags: python, testing, python-import, doctest, coverage.py

From googling and experimentation, it seems python's `coverage` library doesn't include doctests in its calculations. Is there any way to make it do so?

I have searched the docs (https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/coverage-4.4.1/) and found no mention of doctests, but it seems so odd that it wouldn't have *some* way of including them that I feel like I must be missing something.

If I'm right and coverage won't include them, how can I get a measurement of my test coverage without changing all my doctests into unit tests with `unittest` (which I don't want to do)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two ways come to mind, either having the module import itself or loading the module from another module.

### Have the module import itself

In file `a.py`:

```
def linear(a, b):
    ''' Solve ax + b = 0

        >>> linear(3, 5)
        -1.6666666666666667

    '''
    if a == 0 and b != 0:
        raise ValueError('No solutions')
    return -b  / a

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import doctest
    import a

    print(doctest.testmod(a))
```

At the command line:

```
$ coverage run a.py
$ coverage annotate
$ cat a.py,cover
```

This produces:

```
> def linear(a, b):
>     ''' Solve ax + b = 0

>         >>> linear(3, 5)
>         -1.6666666666666667

>     '''
>     if a == 0 and b != 0:
!         raise ValueError('No solutions')
>     return -b  / a

> if __name__ == '__main__':
>     import doctest
>     import a

>     print(doctest.testmod(a))
```

### Run the tests from a separate module

Alternatively, you can move the imports and *testmod()* out of `a.py` and put them in a separate module.

In file `b.py`

```
import doctest
import a

print(doctest.testmod(a))
```

At the command line:

```
$ coverage run b.py
$ coverage annotate
$ cat a.py,cover
```

This produces:

```
> def linear(a, b):
>     ''' Solve ax + b = 0

>         >>> linear(3, 5)
>         -1.6666666666666667

>     '''
>     if a == 0 and b != 0:
!         raise ValueError('No solutions')
>     return -b  / a
```

Comment: But if you have both unittest tests and doctests, won't you need to convert the doctests with `doctest.DocTestSuite` and add them to the unittest test suite ?

Comment: Ah! Didn't realize that just calling the doctests would make them appear in coverage. Of course! Thanks!

Comment: It would be neat to do something like this with NumPy / SciPy documentation testing, but I don't immediately see how to scale these approaches for large packages & to account for subclassing various components of the standard lib doctest infrastructure for custom handling of arrays, etc. We still have `want` and `got` under the hood, but there's also custom things with evals of strings and `np.allclose()` if std lib doctest doesn't pass for an example. Maybe there's still a simple solution to be found, but we don't use testmod() directly.

Comment: I also notice that `coverage html` won't explicitly mark the docstring lines as green, so I think I'll have to take a look at how the static analysis happens for that, compared to `annotate`.

Answer (score 0):

A module's doctests can be converted to a unittest's test suite

```
import mymodule
suite = doctest.DocTestSuite(mymodule)
```